# MATCH function won't work with a cell reference

Tags: excel, indexing, match, cell, lookup

I am trying to use `INDEX`/`MATCH` functions in a spreadsheet with multiple sheets.

Basically, I want Excel to look at the value in cell C3, find the row on another sheet that matches the value of C3, and return the value of the cell in column H in that row.

This formula I wrote below works if I put the value of C3 in quotes (e.g. `"99213"`), but it returns `#N/A` if I use the cell reference itself (e.g. `C3`; see below).

Am I missing something here? If it helps, the values in column C consist of 5-digit alpha-numeric strings, formatted as "General".

```
=INDEX('2015 RVU data'!$H$8:$H$8922,MATCH(C3,'2015 RVU data'!$A$8:$A$8922,0))
```

Comment: This can only happen if you have numeric value in C3 and text values (i.e. preceded with `'` apostrophe) in lookup range or vice versa. What does `=CELL("type",C3)` return?

Comment: That returns a value of "v". I also just tried selecting both columns A and H on the data sheet and formatting them as text. Then I formatted column C as text. That did not change the result, still getting #N/A.

Comment: `=CELL("type",[somewhere in lookup range])` then? Rather that formatting, try putting apostrophe in `C3` (`'99213`).

Comment: That returns a value of "l" -- note this is in the original format, I reversed my formatting changes to get the original results.

Comment: Aha, putting an apostrophe in front of the C3 value fixes it. Is there any way around this? This spreadsheet will be used by people who are easily confused. Ideally I'd like the C column values to not require an apostrophe.

Comment: What sort of values are in column H? If those are numbers then one option is to use SUMIF instead. The advantage of SUMIF here is that the text/number problem shouldn't be an issue - SUMIF will match where MATCH doesn't

Answer (score 2):

It means that your values in `C3` are numeric while values in the lookup range are text. One of the solutions is:

```
=INDEX('2015 RVU data'!$H$8:$H$8922,MATCH(TEXT(C3,"0"),'2015 RVU data'!$A$8:$A$8922,0))
```

Or convert all your values in lookup range to numbers (assuming they all contain only numbers by:

```
=VALUE()
```